# A properties about expoential integral, 5.1.11 in Abramowitz and Stegun

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Dear everyone,

Hi,

How to derive that equation (5.1.11 in Abramowitz and Stegun)

$E_1(z)= - \gamma - \mathrm{ln} z - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n z^n}{n n!} (|arg z|< \pi)$

Thank you very much in advance!!

here the $E_1(z)$ is defined as $E_1(z):=\int_z^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-t} }{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information on this at the following pages:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

The proof for this result is given in this link:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point in the mathworld link, in wikipedia
it is said
$\mathrm{Ein}(z)
= \int_0^z (1-e^{-t})\frac{dt}{t} (1)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}z^k}{k\; k!}
$

from eq (1) we have $E_{\mathrm{in}}(z) = \mathrm{ln} z - \mathrm{ln} 0 -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt + \int_z^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-t}}{t} dt = \mathrm{ln} z - \mathrm{ln} 0 - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-t}}{t} dt + E_1 (z) $, how to get the Euler constant? Thank you for your help


Comment: got a derivation from Bender and Orszag, p253, thx